# Extract a single value from a preg_match() PHP

Tags: php, regex

If I perform the following:

```
preg_match('/[a-z]+.[a-z]+$', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $domain);
```

with `$SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = subdomain.mydomain.com`,
`preg_match()` will create a an array `$domain` which contains all the matches, in this case: `$domain = ["mydomain.com"]`

The result I want is `$domain = "mydomain.com"`

---

My question is, is there a more elegant way to do this than:

```
preg_match('/[a-z]+.[a-z]+$', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $domain);
$domain = $domain[0];
```

Comment: `preg_match` doesn't return an array of all the matches, it just does one match (that's the difference from `preg_match_all()`. The array is for the capture groups.

Comment: The only alternative is `list($domain) = $domain;`

Comment: i would not consider that inelegant.its code, not art, it's their to do a job, not look pretty

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is more elegant or not, but it's a little more direct:

```
$arr = [
    'subdomain.mydomain.com',
    'mydomain.com',
    'subdo.subdomain.mydomain.com'
];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo preg_replace('~(?:.*\.)?(?=.*\.)~', '', $item), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[demo](https://eval.in/755891)